# Can you create a PDF and have a target path such as i have below?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, So i am trying to create a PDf and place it into a a folder that is named after cell E10 in which is side a folder of B18. I am getting a "Compile Error block If Without End If" I have tried both end and exit statements with no luck.

```
Function Dispatch_PDF() As Boolean  ' Copies sheets into new PDF file for e-mailing
 
    Dim Thissheet As String, ThisFile As String, PathName As String
    Dim SvAs As String
    Dim Tmp         As String
    Dim FldName     As String
    
    ' 1. Create the name you want to search for before starting the search
    ' 2. don't refer to cells by their range names (too cumbersome)
    FldName = Cells(10, 5).Value                          ' actually, it's Cells(10, 5)
    Debug.Print FldName                                     ' check the name
    If Len(FldName) Then
        Tmp = Cells(18, 2).Value
        If Len(Tmp) Then
            FldName = Tmp & "\" & FldName                   ' observe how to add the path separator
            Debug.Print FldName                             ' check the name
            FldName = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & FldName
            Debug.Print FldName
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
' Get File Save Name
        Thissheet = ActiveSheet.Name
        ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        PathName = ActiveWorkbook.path
        SvAs = PathName & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & FldName & Range("E10").Value & ".pdf"
 
'Set Print Quality
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
 
' Instruct user how to send
        On Error GoTo RefLibError
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SvAs, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        On Error GoTo 0
    
SaveOnly:
        MsgBox "A copy of this sheet has been successfully saved as a  .pdf  file: " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & SvAs & _
        "Review the .pdf document. If the document does NOT look good, adjust your printing parameters, and try again."
        
    Dispatch_PDF = True
    GoTo EndMacro
    
RefLibError:
    MsgBox "Unable to save as PDF. Reference library not found."
    Dispatch_PDF = False
EndMacro:
    
End Function
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You're missing both `End If` terminators.

Comment: I have tried that. and when i add the end if's i get the library reference not found.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that actually checks for a library reference. So either remove that line of code or change it to reflect what you are actually checking - the values in `E10` and `B18`.

Comment: Take the error trapping out completely, and then you'll get more relevant information.  It will stop on the line that's giving you the problem and give you the native error messages, both of which will be valuable information.